# filter pandas dataframe by two columns where one column is a list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a pandas dataframe by seeing if one columns of strings exists in a column of a list of strings.

**reproducible example:**

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'Letter':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
              'Alpha':[['a', 'z'], ['c', 'q', 'f'], 'c', 'e', ['e', 'q', 'm']]})

       Alpha Letter
0     [a, z]      a
1  [c, q, f]      b
2          c      c
3          e      d
4  [e, q, m]      e
```

Trying to check if Letter is in Alpha.

**Expected Output:**

```
       Alpha Letter
0     [a, z]      a
2          c      c
4  [e, q, m]      e
```

I've tried:

```
x[x.Letter in x.Alpha]

x[x.Letter.isin(x.Alpha)]

x[x.Letter.any(x.Alpha)]
```

was thinking of trying to use a generator to do something like `[a for a in x if a.Letter in a.Alpha]`

If it's any help, I can change the starting point so that everything in `Alpha` is in a list, even if its just 1 letter.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()`:

```
print(x[x.apply(lambda row: row.Letter in row.Alpha, axis=1)])
#       Alpha Letter
#0     [a, z]      a
#2          c      c
#4  [e, q, m]      e
```

Comment: perfect thank you! @pault @Wen out of curiosity, why does `.apply` and a lambda function work over doing x.Letter in x.Alpha

Comment: Someone can probably explain this better but I believe `x.Letter in x.Alpha` attempts to do `Series in Series`, which isn't what you want. You want to do the comparisons row-by-row, which is what `apply()` does. I am not sure if there is a faster (vectorized) solution.

Comment: that definitely helps. thanks for the explanation and solution!

Answer (score 2):

Efficient `zip` solution:

```
y = x[[i in j for i, j in zip(x.Letter, x.Alpha)]]
```

Pandas solution via `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
y = x[x.apply(lambda row: row['Letter'] in row['Alpha'], axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x[x.Alpha.apply(pd.Series).eq(x.Letter,0).any(1)]
Out[1068]: 
       Alpha Letter
0     [a, z]      a
2          c      c
4  [e, q, m]      e
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use apply to create a mask:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'Letter':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
              'Alpha':[['a', 'z'], ['c', 'q', 'f'], 'c', 'e', ['e', 'q', 'm']]})


print(x[x.apply(lambda row:  row['Letter'] in row['Alpha'], axis=1)])
```

output:

```
       Alpha Letter
0     [a, z]      a
2          c      c
4  [e, q, m]      e
```